# Make div inside a "position absolute" div relative to the page

Tags: css

I have a footer div that is an absolute position as I need the design to strench across the page. I also have another div that displays the contents of the footer which lives inside the absolute div. However I need this div (contents) to be relative. i.e. basically when I zoom in and out of the page, it stays in a fixed position. I have something like this thus far.

```
// This is the div inside the absolute footer div 
#FooterContents 
{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#6E6F72; 
    padding:40px;
    left:20px;
    right:20px;
}
```

I thought stating left and right is what I needed, but when I zoom in and out, this div moves.

Thanks

Comment: put your code (html/css) on jsfiddle for us to check and answer you...

Comment: Absolute positioning is a rather unresponsive method of laying out pages. You might want to consider another methodology [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

What im using for my footers for making it bottom center is this code:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
max-width: 800px;
min-height: 170px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Kinda, bascially I need the footer itself to span across the page, so it goes off the flow, so I did this with specifying absolute. However, know the parent is absolute the children divs inside cannot be relative. But I need them to be.